# Is a customer responsible for invalid transcations caused by using machines that fail to discern valid from invalid forms of payment?

Tags: canada, fraud

Canadian law question here.

I was recently accused of using a fraudulent credit card to pay for a parking permit. I used a debit card at the machine to pay, not seeing the small sign on the machine that states the machine does not accept debit cards as a form of payment, and those who use debit cards may be charged with using a fraudulent credit card. However, when I used my debit card, I received a parking permit and a receipt. Even if I had read the sign, I had no way of knowing anything had gone wrong with the transaction (I later looked at my bank records and discovered the transaction had not actually been successful). I explained the situation and the fine was reduced, but I'm still being accused of the same charge.

I suppose my question is this: legally, does the fact that I received the permit and receipt from the machine protect me from this fine and charge?

Comment: Does the "fine" exceed the amount owed for the service or goods you received (i.e., the parking)?

Comment: Yes, and by quite the margin.

Comment: Wait. You were criminally charged with fraud for using a debit card? Sounds like a mistake, and not fraud. Where is this? Sounds like you were charged under 393(2) of the Criminal Code - but even then, there was no "valuable consideration" of any sort.

Comment: Apologies, I should've been clearer: the violation on the parking ticket reads "fraudulent use of credit card"; however, this seems to be just a melodramatic title given to the parking offense in question - I was not (and suspect will not be) criminally charged with fraud.